# Paypal payments pro-Your payment has been declined. Please try again

Tags: magento2, error, paypal-pro

I am using paypal payments pro. configure paypal pro using sandbox mode .when we fill all credit card details on front end and tr to place order but order does not placed display below error message.
Please Help me how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Enable debug mode from admin panel & check log report.

Comment: checked log file error is   'result' => 
  array (
    'result' => '26',
    'respmsg' => 'Invalid vendor account',
    'result_code' => '26',
  ),
) {"is_exception":false} []

Comment: 'respmsg' => 'Invalid vendor account' this is your error

Comment: Where you able to find the solution for this error?

Comment: @Devidas Where Magento create a Paypal Log file? I don't found in /var/log/. Can you please guide me?

Comment: @pankajDadure First check magento log enable or disabel and another check paypal payment method debug mode set yes or no

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PayPal API credential.

Also please check your currency and country in magento setting.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/currency_codes/